# Problem with "alignedat" block: minus not correctly spaced

Tags: spacing, alignment

I have an "issue" with the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
    \begin{math}
        \Leftrightarrow \left\{
        \begin{alignedat}{1}
            &c = -4a + 2b + 3 \\
            &-3a + 3b + 3 = 6 \\
            &4b + 3 = 15
        \end{alignedat}
        \right.
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Minus not aligned.]

As we can see, the minus of the second line is not correctly aligned (too much forward).

Now check the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
    \begin{math}
        \Leftrightarrow \left\{
        \begin{alignedat}{2}
            &&c = -4a + 2b + 3 \\
            &&-3a + 3b + 3 = 6 \\
            &&4b + 3 = 15
        \end{alignedat}
        \right.
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Minus aligned but third line gone away.]

We can see that the minus of the second line is now correctly aligned, but the third line completly gone away... We can also note that the minus is closer to the "3a".

My question is: how I can do to get both minus aligned and third line correctly in its place? Like in the following image (which is a photomontage):

[image: The result that I'm looking for.]

Thanks for help and regards.

Comment: Your 2nd alignment is normal: you indicated two alignment columns, but specified only one alignment point, so by default the alignment of the second column is at the end of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `\{` or `\[` for such things. `amsmath` already give you `cases` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
c = -4a + 2b + 3 \\
-3a + 3b + 3 = 6 \\
4b + 3 = 15
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you explain me the usefulness of the `\[`, `\]` in the present case?

Comment: @MissingBracket They are LaTeX (not TeX) commands for display-style math-mode. You can change them to `$` (it becomes in-line math-mode), or `\begin{math}` and `\end{math}` without any problems.

Comment: Could you please provide an answer which maintains the alignedat2 environment? It would suit my problem perfectly, for which I can't use the cases environment, and it seems a bit inappropriate to me to ask a separate question for such a tiny detail. The problem I'm facing, for which I can't use the cases environment, is strictly related to the one exposed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469632/incorrect-horizontal-spacing-in-cases-mode. Thank you for your attention.